# d3js accept/revert input values

Tags: d3.js

I fill a set of text input fields displaying values of an associative array  using d3js. The user changes some input values.

```
var obj = {a: 'Hello', b: 'World'}
var kk = function(d){return d.key}
var kv = function(d){return d.value}
var upd = function(c){
    c.select('div.label').text(kk)
    c.select('div.input input').attr("value", kv)
}
var data = d3.entries(obj)
var prop = d3.select("div.container").selectAll("div.prop").data(data, kk)
upd(prop)
var eprop = prop.enter().append("div").attr("class", "prop")
eprop.append("div").attr("class", "label")
eprop.append("div").attr("class", "input").append("input").attr("name", kk)
upd(eprop)
prop.exit().remove()
```

What are the best practices to
a) update the original associative array from DOM (opposite direction)
b) revert the DOM values to the original ones

My current solutions are
a) iterating over the input fields  `d3.select("div.container").selectAll("div.prop").select('div.input input').each(function(){obj[this.name]=this.value})`
b) assigning `[]` as selection data and then back the original data (I have not found anything like force update or refresh)

**Edit (generalized)**
Input fields displaying values of an associative array is only a special case, you can imagine any d3js layout applied on a model with user interaction.
But generally:
a) accept the values from the DOM back to the source data
b) revert the DOM to the actual source data
Is there any d3js built-in support or a d3js plugin for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found simple and built-in solutions for accept:

```
prop.select('div.input input').datum(function(d){obj[d.key]=(d.value=this.value);return d})
```

and revert:

```
upd(prop.datum(function(d){return(d)}))
```

I tried this already before, but there was an error on this line:

```
c.select('div.input input').attr("value", kv)
```

The correct code is here:

```
c.select('div.input input').property("value", kv)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is `obj` for?

Comment: @CoolBlue it is an associative array, see codesnippet in the question. but if you have a normal array, you can skip the assignment `obj[d.key]=` and the brackets

Answer (score 2):

You really need to provide some code because from your question it's tough to tell how you are using d3 to manage your inputs.  I'm assuming you are data-binding in some fashion so I just coded this up for fun.  It's shows some of the cools ways to use `enter/append`, `data()` and `datum()` to manage groups of input and their values:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="report">Report</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <script>
    var data = [{
      v: Math.random()
    }, {
      v: Math.random()
    }, {
      v: Math.random()
    }, {
      v: Math.random()
    }, {
      v: Math.random()
    }, {
      v: Math.random()
    }];

    var inputs = d3.select('body')
      .append('div')
      .selectAll('input')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('input')
      .attr('type','text')
      .attr('value', function(d) {
        return d.v;
      })
      .on('blur', function(d) {
        d._v = d.v;
        d.v = this.value;
      });
      
    d3.select('#report')
      .on('click',function(){
        alert(inputs.data().map(function(d){
          return d.v;
        }).join("\n"));
      });
      
    d3.select('#reset')
      .on('click',function(){
        inputs.each(function(d){
          if (d._v){
            this.value = d._v;
            d.v = d._v;
            d._v = null;
          }
        });
      });
      
      
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so you mean to use a copy of original data to handle this situation is the best solution? I wonder there is no built-in support. (imagine a user interaction with some visualized model having thousands nodes)

Comment: @PavelGatnar, I know of no built-ins for this.  I know of at least one canonical Bostock example which follows the same method I use: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Comment: yes, I know this example. there is this pattern used for showing/hiding nodes

Comment: thanks for your help, I found an error and the built-in solution for revert